# Unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in #include <Python.h>

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano

After installing Theano and import it, I run into such trouble.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please paste information in your question rather than providing links.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the 64 bit version of Anaconda Python and didn't install the 32 bit version?